# amChart add % value to funnel report

Tags: amcharts

How to remove value from the legend but not the text.
How to add '%' icon in funnel graph box.[image]

Can we only put the percent value in funnel ie 26%. And in legend I want to put the whole text ie value and percentage both. Please help accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the label on the funnel chart slices, change [`labelText`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmFunnelChart#labelText) to the desired value. By default it is set to `[[title]]: [[value]]`, but you can change it to `[[percents]]%` if you just want the percent value.

For the legend, you have to set the legend's [`valueText`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueText). This is set to `[[value]]` by default, so you can add `[[percents]]%` to it as well:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  labelText: "[[percents]]%",
  legend: {
    valueText: "[[value]] ([[percents]]%)",
    valueWidth: 75, //you might also need to increase the valueWidth to add more space
    // ...
  },
  // ...
});
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "funnel",
  "theme": "light",
  "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
  "legend": {
    "valueText": "[[value]] ([[percents]]%)",
    "valueWidth": 75
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
    "title": "Website visits",
    "value": 300
  }, {
    "title": "Downloads",
    "value": 123
  }, {
    "title": "Requested prices",
    "value": 98
  }, {
    "title": "Contacted",
    "value": 72
  }],
  "titleField": "title",
  "marginRight": 160,
  "marginLeft": 15,
  "labelPosition": "right",
  "funnelAlpha": 0.9,
  "valueField": "value",
  "startX": 0,
  "neckWidth": "40%",
  "startAlpha": 0,
  "labelPosition": "center",
  "outlineThickness": 1,
  "neckHeight": "30%",
  "balloonText": "[[title]]:<b>[[value]]</b>",
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```